# Script files as resource or solution project?

Tags: c#, design

I've written a program for another group within my company that uses scripts.  These scripts are user selected by the use of two drop down lists: category and name.  Currently the application uses an XML file that is on a network share to populate the drop down lists with the scripts and their associated categories and titles.  The XML file also contains the network path location where the scripts are housed as well as title, description and usage details.

I am trying to decide on the better way to manage access to the scripts without allowing the end users to be able to edit them with a text editor.  I've been going between adding them as a project within the solution or adding them as references.  Does anyone have any thought on either of those options or possibly a better solution?

EDIT: I think I may have figured out a solution for what I'm looking to do.  [http://support.microsoft.com/kb/319292](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/319292run).  I'll load the macros as well as the XML file and that should allow me to accomplish what I'm trying to do.

Comment: What are the scripts?  Are they user-written *.js files, programs created by a technician, or the product of some "record" feature?

Comment: @DougM the scripts are "macros" that myself and two other members on my dev team write for the users.  Right now they are text files that we just create/edit with Notepad++ but we were considering making them part of the C# project.